# Event fired with BeginInvoke raises exception, but doesn't if fired with Invoke

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, .net-core

I have a library (.NET Standard 2.0) and the corresponding (.NET Core 3.1 - WPF) test-project.

In the library, I have a class (`Configurator`) with a simple notification based on delegate and event with the following signatures:

```
public delegate void ConfiguratorStatusChanged(int newStatus);
public event ConfiguratorStatusChanged ConfigurationStatusChanged;
```

Inside test-project calling code, I make a dummy subscription to the event in this way:

```
Configurator.ConfiguratorStatusChanged += (newStatus) => { /*no code at all*/ };
```

Then, in library code, I should be able to fire my event in a synchronous way with `Invoke`:

```
ConfiguratorStatusChanged?.Invoke(_newStatus);
```

or in an asynchronous way with `BeginInvoke`:

```
ConfiguratorStatusChanged?.BeginInvoke(_newStatus, null, null);
```

The synchronous way works fine (actually doing nothing) while the asynchronous way raises a *System.PlatformNotSupportedException: 'Operation is not supported on this platform.'*; I expect also the asynchronous way to work fine (actually doing nothing) but that's not the case; I have set the second (`AsyncCallback callback`) and third (`object @object`) parameter to null because I do not need any control over the notification, just it to be fired towards calling code.

The question is: why is the asynchronous way faulty?

Comment: That is because `.Net Core` doesn't support the `Delegate.BeginInvoke`, [check out](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/16312#issuecomment-182107557) that link as Jan Kotas discusses this. Also further in that post, they discuss why it's not a compile error vs runtime error; it shouldn't even exist in core.

Comment: What is the question to answer here? If you need to be able to asynchronously fire events, execute the `Invoke` call using `Task.Run` and do not `await` the result.

Comment: @Julius I have edited the question to make It clearer; I get your point, I was just trying to understand why BeginInvoke behaves like this.

Comment: @Codexer I will check in details the link you provided